Screen flashes white when booting
I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my laptop as a dual boot setup. Everything works, but I've noticed an issue during the boot process that's quite bothersome:

After selecting Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, there is a blinking
cursor that stays on the screen for a while.
Following this, the screen flashes white briefly (like a camera
flash).
Once I reach the login screen and enter my password, the white flashes
happen again before the desktop loads.

While this doesn't seem to affect the functionality of the system, the flashing white screen is uncomfortable to look at and disrupts the booting experience.
I’d like to understand:

What could be causing this white flash during the boot and login
process?
How can I fix or mitigate this issue?

For reference:

My laptop has a dual-boot configuration with Ubuntu and Windows 10 Home.
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.
System Configuration
List hardware as seen by the system

